# Which statistical tests to perform for my survey study?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, survey

I'm designing a survey study (with non-probability sampling) with the following alternate hypotheses:

1. Usage of the system varies among the three groups (three groups of unequal sizes)
2. Factor/Construct 1 positively affects usage of the system
3. Factor/Construct 2 positively affects usage of the system
4. Factor/Construct 3 positively affects usage of the system
5. There is significant difference between actual use and potential use

I may also want to test the hypotheses 2 to 5 for each of the three groups to see if there is a difference in the relationship among the groups.

With my limited knowledge of statistics, I'm unable to figure out which tests to perform.
I am thinking Factor analysis, ANOVA. Heard of SEM but don't know when one should use it and whether it's applicable in my case.

I've looked at a research paper with similar research questions and they have used ANOVA (to test significant difference) , Linear Regression (effect of factors on dependent variable),

Any pointers would greatly help.

Comment: Do you already know which items (questions) in your survey measure each construct? Do you want to test the proposition that they do? If not, you won't need the FA.

Comment: I gathered items for each construct from literature. Pooled up different models and constructs. I haven't adopted any existing constructs as is. There are a few additions and deletions.